# Where can I watch the JoJo OVA from the 90s?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure, streaming-sites

I was wondering if anyone knew where I could watch either the sub or dub of the 1993 *Stardust Crusaders* OVA?

Comment: Hi, just a standard legal notice that this site doesn't condone piracy, so we will only mention legal/official sites if they exist. Answers/comments that mention questionable sites will be removed without prompt.

Comment: yeah, id prefer a legit website anyways but I understand you have to post the legal notice.

Comment: I don't know, but you should first watch the OVA from 2000 and then the one from 1993, as the later one is Jojo Part 3 the first half and the earlier one is Jojo Part 3 the second half. Also, don't bother with the movie from 2007. It doesn't exist anymore. The author didn't like it and ordered it's destruction.

Comment: @Ocean i was aware of the destruction of the movie but that won't stop me from searching every corner of the earth to find it

Comment: @Ocean i belive this website may give me a bit of a lead on the movie so wish me luck https://lostmediawiki.com/JoJo%27s_Bizarre_Adventure:_Phantom_Blood_(partially_found_anime_film_based_on_manga;_2007)

Comment: If you ever find it, let me know.

Comment: @Ocean trust me I will I would never hide something like that from anyone